# Docker: Error while executing 'docker run hello-world' command

Tags: windows, docker

I have installed docker toolbox for Windows 7 64 bit system. I am getting following error while executing 'docker run hello-world' command .
Please guide me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance!

```
$ docker run hello-world  
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
78445dd45222: Pulling fs layer
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error pulling image configuration: G
et https://dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha
256/48/48b5124b2768d2b917edcb640435044a97967015485e812545546cbed5cf0233/data?Exp
ires=1484910885&Signature=DsT7p2RzmUsymlHz2qG51UJspf9ZvTvHF2pjxJPEi1~c9SomNSk2dv
Sqn1UEpsuse3iVmkq37HKT7cEvRaPsu5vB1RlHBgUg6FJB0DGukLBIq1t2hddVPvlI4Q7lm5B5j3NzRI
vj-hYXrAYDxKAM3TX6LsIdrSrmTHlyIZJ4~1A_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJECH5M7VWIS5YZ6Q: read tc
p 10.0.2.15:40664->52.222.190.31:443: read: connection reset by peer.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a connection issue. Try using a `different internet connection` or using a `vpn` or an `http proxy`.

Whitelisting DockerHub's IPs:

Docker Hub doesn't have static IP that can be whitelist. Docker Hub is based on Amazon ELB, so they can change any time.

You can do the following and add a subset of ips, May work for you for a short period of time.

```
dig +noall +answer index.docker.io
;; ANSWER SECTION:
index.docker.io.        174     IN      CNAME   elb-io.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io.
elb-io.us-east-1.aws.dckr.io. 465 IN    CNAME   us-east-1-elbio-rm5bon1qaeo4-623296237.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1-elbio-rm5bon1qaeo4-623296237.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 174 IN A 52.200.132.201
us-east-1-elbio-rm5bon1qaeo4-623296237.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 174 IN A 52.45.107.172
us-east-1-elbio-rm5bon1qaeo4-623296237.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 174 IN A 52.22.146.88
```

On windows, try `nslookup`.

Comment: I have tried in different network then it worked. However, I want to use it in my wokplace network where I am getting above mentioned issue due to some restriction as per comapny policy. Is there any other way to deal with this? Anyone has idea about the IP range for docker hub from where it downloads the image in the background?

Comment: Try using a proxy server or vpn.